# passing intent from inside a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

i have a ListView Code that makes a toast message when a listview option is clicked.
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
            "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit",
            "Jackfruit", "Mango", "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // no more this
        // setContentView(R.layout.list_fruit);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main,FRUITS));

        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

the xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp" >
</TextView>
```

what i want to do is to pass an intent when i click an option inside the the listview options displayed

this is the code that i have tried so far

```
String str = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                Log.i(str, str + "");
//              str2 = FRUITS[Position];
                String s = str + ".class";
                Log.d(s, s + "");
                Intent myintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ListViewSampleClass.class);
                startActivity(myintent);
```

Comment: @Emmanuel please do read the last line

Comment: What I meant to say is "what have you tried so far?, this is a question that has been asked many times before, you do not show any research effort"

Comment: @Emmanuel im gonna edit and post what i have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // This will call another activity using intent
            Intent myintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), youcalssname.class);
            startActivity(myintent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: this is working. but how do i specifically go to an intended view. for example, i chose apple then the view will go to the apple.class.

Comment: you need to put switch case for `position`. `position` argument in `onItemClick()` represent the item which has been clicked. So lets assume if apple position is 2 you can display class according to that position. Let me know if still if you find any difficulty.

Comment: to get name of selected item you can use `FRUITS[position]` this will give name of item which has been selected

Comment: how do i put that FRUITS[position] to string?

Comment: `FRUITS[position]` will return string value only as 'FRUITS` is string array

Answer (score 1):

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

```
static final String[] FRUITS = new String[] { "Apple", "Avocado", "Banana",
        "Blueberry", "Coconut", "Durian", "Guava", "Kiwifruit",
        "Jackfruit", "Mango", "Olive", "Pear", "Sugar-apple" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // no more this
    // setContentView(R.layout.list_fruit);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_main,FRUITS));

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            ((TextView) view).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            passIntentToAnotherActivity();
        }
    });

}

private void passIntentToAnotherActivity() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
    ...
    // Rest of your intent code goes here. 
}
```

}